# Creating one single string from multiple values of array in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this

```
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
```

I want to create a single string like this

```
color-red color-blue color-green
```

to use in a class

```
<div class="${colors_list}">
   Content
</div>
```

I tried to use like this

```js
var colors_list = '';
colors.forEach(function(color) { 
    colors_list = `color-${color}`;
})
```

but the output is `color-red, blue`

Comment: `color.map(x => 'color-' + x).join(' ')`

or

`colors.forEach(function(color) {  colors_list.push(\`color-${color}\`); })`

In your for-each, you need to push the value into new array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var colors_list = '';
colors.forEach(function(color) { 
    colors_list += `color-${color} `;
})
```

or

```
var colors_list = colors.map(x => 'color-' + x).join(' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this,

```
var colors_list = colors.map(c => `color-${c}`).join(' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use map or:

```js
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

console.log(`color-${colors.join(' color-')}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, you could reduce the array and get a string with prefix in front of every color and a space between the items.

```js
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
    string = colors.reduce((s, c) => s + (s && ' ') + 'color-' + c, '');

console.log(string);
```

Comment: Nah. That is huge overkill

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
var colors_list = '';
colors.forEach((color) => colors_list += `color-${color} `)
console.log(colors_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just adding the `+` to after `=` like this

```
 var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

 var colors_list = '';
  colors.forEach(function(color) {
  colors_list += `color-${color} `;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Brother, you can try this. Thank you.

```js
const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

const color_list = colors.map(color => `color-${color}`);

console.log(color_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want!

```
var colors_list = '';
    colors.forEach(function(color) { 
        colors_list += `color-${color} `;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
let result = '';

for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  result = `${result} color-${colors[i]}`
}

console.log(result) // => color-red color-blue color-green
```